# Merge two csv files horizontally with different columns

Tags: shell, csv

I am trying to merge two csv files horizontally.

I used this command:

```
paste -d ',' file1.csv file2.csv> results.csv
```

But it shows the merging with output of second csv on second line. Like this:

```
"Shares of Apple, Inc. near ex-dividend as it gears up to distribute $2.7 ...",Apple Inc. (AAPL),"May 8, 2014"

,0.125,0.0,pos
```

It should have been like this:

```
"Shares of Apple, Inc. near ex-dividend as it gears up to distribute $2.7 ...",Apple Inc. (AAPL),"May 8, 2014",0.125,0.0,pos
```

#### file1.csv

```
"Shares of Apple, Inc. near ex-dividend as it gears up to distribute $2.7 ...",Apple Inc. (AAPL),"May 8, 2014"
Apple Woos Dr. Dre With $3.2 Billion Offer for Beats to Fend Off Spotify as ...,Apple Inc. (AAPL),"May 8, 2014"
```

#### file2.csv

```
0.125,0.0,pos
0.0,0.75,neg
```

How to rectify this?

Comment: Could you please post the first lines of your files?

Comment: It's possible your input files have CRLF because it works well here.

Comment: @alvits: The merged file contains blank spaces between rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @alvits. I converted my file to unix file using this:

```
 awk '{ gsub("\r", "\n"); print $0;}' macfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```

Works fine now.